# Reference to superclass how can I use subclass methods

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Wasn't sure how to call my title, because I'm not sure how to call that problem right now.
I got `one superclass` and `three subclasses`. The `subclasses` only got an own `cunstructor`, all other methods and attributes are listed in the `superclass`.
Now one of those three `subclasses` have to contain a new attribute `delay` and a method for that. But if I implement a somewhat `generic` method (because it doesn't care which subclass is using it, because it checks it in the method itself.) but in the superclass in the method I want that if my object is of that specific subclass that it can access the delay.

Anyone can tell me how to achieve this without implementing the attribute into the superclass itself? (Only want that an object this subclass can access this delay attribute)

```
else if (this instanceof repairCar) {
    if(this.getDelay() != 0){
    }
}
```

Edit:

There is the superclass: `Car`

```
This contains methods like setSpeed and corresponding attributes 
ant a method called drive.
```

now there are the subclasses: `FastCar` `NormalCar` `RepairCar`
which all only got a constructor in the subclass.

The RepairCar should have another attribute `delay` due to it being repaired right now.

In the superclass in the `drive method` it checks whether the Car is a `FastCar`, `NormalCar` or `RepairCar`. When it is a `RepairCar` it should check if the delay is 0 so It can drive otherwise it will wait a turn and lower the delay until its 0.

Now I want that only my RepairCar got this delay attribute and not my other two subclasses. But if my drive method is in the superclass it wont let me reference to the delay of a RepairCar due to the superclass not having this attribute.

Any way to implement the drive method for all 3 Cartypes in the Superclass without implementing the delay into the superclass?

Comment: Where do you want to use the delay? Show us the bigger picture.

Comment: This sounds totally messed-up. Please show ALL relevant code/classes.

Comment: sorry for the mess.. Updated it and made it clearly (I hope)

Comment: Your're doing it backwards...

Comment: In general, a superclass should not know anything about it's subclasses (not even that they exist.) Look into abstract methods. The drive-method should be abstract, and implemented in each of the subclasses (since it has a different course of action for different subclasses.) If it is the same for all but one subclass, implement it in the superclass and override it in the one subclass.

Comment: somethind like: `(RepairCar)this.getDelay()` ? this didn't work for me. @Tobb so I have to make my Car class abstract for this way?

Comment: I'd suggest do not try to access delay attribute, instead create a method in the `RepariCar` class and call this method from `AbstractCar`.

Comment: This is exactly the situation where I would use an abstract class

Answer (score 1):

Why should the superclass be responsible for this? This should only be done by the specific class.

E.g.

```
public class Car {
    public void drive() {
       // do something all cars do
    }
}
```

Your subclass is:

```
public class RepairCar extends Car {
    public int delay() {
       return this.delay;
    }

    @Override
    public void drive() {
       if (delay() == 0) {
         super.drive();
       } else {
         decreaseDelay();
       }
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
abstract class AbstractCar {

    public void performAction() {
        // stuff
        doSomething();
    }

    protected abstract void doSomething();

    static class RepairCar extends AbstractCar  {

        private int delay;

        @Override
        protected void doSomething() {
            // do something based on delay
        }
    }

    static class FastCar extends AbstractCar  {

        @Override
        protected void doSomething() {
            // do something with no delay
        }
    } 
}
```